# Python: using a variable in a method in the same class

Tags: python

I've been doing some researching, but so far, I've come across nothing that replicates my problem fully.

Here's what I'm attempting to do:

```
class FilterClass:
    ALPHABETIC = "a";
    NUMERIC = "n"
    URL = "u";
    def textRestriction(self, text, arguments):
        if ALPHABETIC in arguments:
            #do crap here
        if NUMERIC in arguments:
            #do other crap here
```

I've created variables in class `FilterClass`. They are to be used outside the class, as well as the methods in the class itself, but they will never be modified.

I'm encountering that `global name 'ALPHABETIC' is not defined` error, and adding the variable in the method and adding a global to it does nothing. I also tried adding the `__init__` method, but it did nothing as well.

Can anyone tell me where did I went wrong?

Comment: `if FilterClass.ALPHABETIC in arguments:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created class variables, so you just need to add the class name as follows:

```
class FilterClass:
    ALPHABETIC = "a"
    NUMERIC = "n"
    URL = "u"

    def textRestriction(self, text, arguments):
        if FilterClass.ALPHABETIC in arguments:
            print 'Found alphabetic'
        if FilterClass.NUMERIC in arguments:
            print 'Found numeric'

fc = FilterClass()
fc.textRestriction('test', 'abc n')
```

This would display:

```
Found alphabetic
Found numeric
```

Also, you do not need to add `;` after your variables.

Answer (score 1):

Instance attributes in python need to be referenced as `self.identifier`, not just `identifier`.
Class attributes in python can be referenced either as `self.identifier` or `ClassName.identifier`.

So you mean:

```
def textRestriction(self, text, arguments):
    if FilterClass.ALPHABETIC in arguments:
        #do crap here
    if FilterClass.NUMERIC in arguments:
        #do other crap here
```

Answer (score 0):

You created *class attributes*; you'll need to reference them on the class:

```
class FilterClass:
    ALPHABETIC = "a"
    NUMERIC = "n"
    URL = "u"

    def textRestriction(self, text, arguments):
        if FilterClass.ALPHABETIC in arguments:
            #do crap here
        if FilterClass.NUMERIC in arguments:
            #do other crap here
```

Class attributes are not globals, nor is the class body definition a scope as far as the methods on the class are concerned.

You could also just reference them as if they are *instance* attributes; Python will automatically look for class attributes if there is no such instance attribute:

```
def textRestriction(self, text, arguments):
    if self.ALPHABETIC in arguments:
        #do crap here
    if self.NUMERIC in arguments:
        #do other crap here
```

Another way of accessing these names is by querying for the *current* class with `type(self)`, which would allow for subclasses to override the attributes, but ignore instance attributes:

```
def textRestriction(self, text, arguments):
    if type(self).ALPHABETIC in arguments:
        #do crap here
    if type(self).NUMERIC in arguments:
        #do other crap here
```